# Qt - qmake -project, why is it stuck?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm trying to execute the `qmake -project` command by doing:

`C:\Qt\2010.05\qt>qmake -project`

But, it remains there and doesn't get executed. Why is that?

Thanks.

Comment: why do you execute it in the Qt folder and not your project folder)?

Comment: @Frank Osterfeld. You are right. I moved the project to a separate folder and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`qmake -project` without any additional arguments will traverse the current directory recursively, looking for e.g. source, header and UI files to be included in the .pro file. When you run it in a directory containing lots of files (such as Qt folder), it can take a lot of time to go through all of them. Thats why it seems to get stuck.

Answer (score 0):

`qmake -project -norecursive` may solve the problem, I use qmake with VSCode and there is an `.vscode` subdirectory, delete `.vscode` folder or use `-norecursive` both solves the problem for me.