# why is qmake hanging

Tags: qt, qt5

I am working with qt5.7 (the latest version now), in ubuntu, and creating a project with "qmake -project". This command hangs infinitely, with no outputs and no files created, so I had to kill it. However 2 days ago, after I installed qt5 for the first time, it had worked fine for a simple HelloWorld program. I have not changed anything in my system during the last 2 days.

I tried googling for a solution, and this page (http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-2269.html) says that if the subdirectory under PWD is large, then this is expected, so I should use "-norecursive" option.

Well, adding this option actually solved my problem, and now it creates the .pro file. However, I dont have any subdirectories, I am working in a newly created directory. But I do have other sibling directories in which I have tried out other qt projects.

Any ideas why this is hanging, and why -norecursive solves it?

(BTW, there exists another old question on the same topic: [Qt - qmake -project, why is it stuck?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5469557), but I dont see any relevant answers there.)

Answer (score 0):

`qmake -project` is kind of a crutch and not very widely tested. What you're facing is a known deficiency and you're free to fix it and submit a change to Qt's gerrit.

Feel free to create the project files individually in each folder, then merge them. You really should be managing these manually, `qmake -project` output only works for fairly simple projects.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I ran "qmake -project" before I created main.cpp, so it hung up (but it should have given some warning at least).
Agreed with Kuba, that qmake is only a crutch. Now I am taking .pro files from other projects and editing them as per my need.